# {if a < 50}...{elif a>50 and a<75}....{else} could not be parsed

Tags: django, if-statement, django-templates

I want to use a template in Django 1.6 where what will be displayed depends on the interval in which the value of a variable is.

For example,

```
{if a < 50} (case 1)
{elif a>50 and a<75} (case 2)
{else} (case 3)
```

so: if a equals 80, the template displays the case '3', if a is 30, it's the case '1', etc...

But I've got the error:

```
Could not parse the remainder
```

I've tried with a nested `if` (but apparently, Django 1.6 supports `elif`) but it did not work.

Apparently, it's the case '2' which is the problem since deleting that makes it run normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `%` character in the tags. You also need a `{% endif %}` tag to finish your conditional block:

```
{% if a < 50 %} 
    (case 1)
{% elif a < 75 %} 
    (case 2)
{% else %} 
    (case 3)
{% endif %}
```

Note that the `a > 50` is useless in your `elif` since you are sure it is true (otherwise, it would have executed the "case 1".

Reference: [Built-in template tags and filters - `if` (Django documentation)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-if)

Comment: it works! Thanks a lot! Of course there were the '%' and '%endif%' in my initial code.